# UIViewController's view has weird 20px y margin

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am adding a UIViewController's view to another UIViewController's views (using the new UIViewController Containment APIs). After adding the vc's view as another's subivew, there's a weird 20px margin from the top.

I logged the view and it's from origin was 0,0. However, I when I log the view's superview, it's:

```
<UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x6c5e2c0; frame = (0 20; 703 748); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c54190>>
```

I can obviously change it's frame to 0,0. But i am wondering what's the right way to do this? Why is the vc's view's superview's frame 0,20? Should I modify this or is there a better way to go around this weird margin?

Thanks

Comment: iOS 6 is still under an NDA, but my guess is it has to do with the status bar.

Comment: what does iOS 6 have to do with this? The Containment APIs are from iOS 5. I said new because they are relatively new.

Comment: My bad, I thought by containment APIs you meant Xcode 4.5's view controller containment (since you mentioned it was new), but UIViewController containment APIs were introduced in iOS 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. Need to call addChildViewController: on self. So, here's the sequence of calls you need to make to get the containment to work properly:

```
[self addChildViewController:navVC];
[navVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[mainView addSubview:navVC.view];
```

self is the parent view controller. navVC is the child view controller you are adding. mainView is the view in parent view controller to which you ae going to add child view controller's view.

Comment: Came across the same problem today and navVC.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;  helped me.

Comment: you saved my life <3 In my situation I simply removed the addChildViewController() line and somehow it still works... do you know why is it "important" to add this line? I m using iOS8 and swift, i don t even know if it's still important to do it... At least it causes a dirty bug

Comment: It's important to have `addChildViewController` to keep your view controller hierarchy in sync with your view hierarchy. If you don't, you have to come up with your own strong reference to it, or else it won't be retained. Furthermore, your child view controller won't get certain events if it's not in the view controller hierarchy. BTW, the call to `didMoveToParentViewController` should be the last thing you do, after adding the subview.

Answer (score 16):

To fix this problem just `check the box "Wants Full Screen"` on the storyboard.

The problem appears because the ParentViewController is showing the navigation bar.

As apple documentation said :

If your app displays the status bar, the view shrinks so that it does not underlap the status bar. After all, if the status bar is opaque, there is no way to see or interact with the content lying underneath it. However, if your app displays a translucent status bar, you can set the value of your view controller’s wantsFullScreenLayout property to YES to allow your view to be displayed full screen. The status bar is drawn over the top of the view.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the code below, works for me.

```
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: +1 although I phrased it as  self.pageController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

Comment: Don't forget to place it under -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {...}

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to add one line before first view controller load

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you tried setting the Status Bar pull down menu to "none", check the size properties of your view, too.  Make sure it's not still got some hard-coded height value of 460, or y origin of 20 (in Xcode's graphical designer).  And if you want this view to fill its entire parent view, then make sure the autoresizing mask is set in properties to be pinned to all sides (top, left, bottom, right) and probably set to stretch, too.

Just looking at your debug output, it looks like maybe the autoresizing properties are only set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`.

Finally, the containing view probably needs to have its **Autoresize Subviews** checkbox checked.

Comment: Autoresize subviews is check on the containing view. View's origin in IB is greyed out but shows value of x:0 y:0. I tried adding flexible margin to all sides. No luck.

Comment: @0xSina, is Status Bar Style specified in your app's Info.plist file?

Comment: No, I didn't set anything specific, it's the default plist. I didn't touch info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the wantsFullScreenLayout property. If set to YES the view will extend below the UIStatusBar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it in IOS 9 by using constraints (in interface builder). I did not use full screen because it is deprecated.
Add a leading and a trailingMargin constraint and give them the Constant -20

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although I have no experience with the containment APIs, I've solved many "off-by-20" problems by setting the status bar to None (see below) in the Identity Inspector.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the input. I tried that, setting status bar to none in Interface Builder but still no luck. I even tried instantiating the view controller without a nib, same thing.

Comment: Like it is said, it is only simulated.

Answer (score -9):

Just use this viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Putting "height=device-height" in there will cause this problem.